# How set default API definition url in openapi?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I want set default scheme by url `/v3/api-docs/`, but there are empty url and error "No API definition provided.".
Which settings properties I should use?

Current code in project:

application.properties

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

@Bean
public GroupedOpenApi applicationApi() {
    String packagesToScan[] = {"ru.vetrf.ecert.web.application"};
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("application")
            .pathsToMatch("/rest-api/application/**")
            .packagesToScan(packagesToScan)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public OpenAPI eCertOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info().title("ECert API")
                    .description("ECert API")
                    .version("v1.0.0"))
            ;
}
```

}

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Of the two screenshots you shared, do you mean to say, the first is what is happening while the second is what you want? I'm a little confused as to what issue you're facing.

Comment: I want so that second screenshot opens by default, when I open /swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 2):

For all upgrade to swagger-ui 4.1.3, pls check below:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases/tag/v4.1.3

**Note: to re-enable the functionality of reading config params from URL, set new queryConfigEnabled core parameter to true. More info in documentation.**

Answer (score 2):

With the latest version of `springdoc-openapi-ui` for me, it was 1.6.7
I updated my spring boot application config YAML to the following and it worked:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    config-url: /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    url: /v3/api-docs
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it worked for me this way

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    query-config-enabled: true
  api-docs:
    path: /my-service/v3/api-docs
```

testing some properties, I found that this parameter does the magic :)

```
query-config-enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

This Configuration worked for me. @tatka

> springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
>
> springdoc.swagger-ui.urlsPrimaryName=myGroup

Answer (score 0):

Tried reproducing the same but the current set of properties that you're using works fine for me.

Hopefully adding the below property to your application.properties should help

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl=/v3/api-docs/
```

Answer (score 0):

This property seems to use the **springdoc.swagger-ui.config_url** path:

**springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true**

This property seems to say, use config_url path as root path in explore field
in swagger-ui.

I found the solution in looking in the demo repository for spring-doc openapi

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi-demos/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-spring-boot-2-webmvc/src/main/resources/application.yml

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, all properties have been set correctly but the default value in the `Explore` Text Field was empty, and `No API definition provided.` was rendered. Update of `springdoc-openapi-ui` from `1.5.` to  `1.6` has solved the problem.